# how to change webgrid view to list view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display static data in list view. I have pulled the data and displayed in the grid view by using webgrid in mvc4.

I want to display the data in the list view, can anyone please tell how do i display data in listview.

This is my code in view

```
<div id="gridContent" class="list">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("FName","FName"),
            grid.Column("LName", " LName"),
            grid.Column("Age","Age"),
            grid.Column("Email","Email"),
            grid.Column("Contact","Contact")
            )
            )
</div>
```

Static data to display data to webgrid
    controller:

```
 public ActionResult WebGridSample()
 {
    List<EmployeeDetails> emp = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
    emp.Add(new EmployeeDetails { FName = "John", LName = "Adam", Age = "21", Email = "john@123.@gmail.com", Contact = "978546320" });
    return View("WebGridSample",emp);
 }
```

model:

```
  public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

Note: list view such as search results in e-commerce sites.

```
Fname 
___________________________________________
LName
___________________________________________
Age
____________________________________________
```

http://www.vandelaydesign.com/list-grid-view-switch/

Comment: You have to leave current approach to bind your webGrid. Loop statements are best options to display data as you want.

Comment: Thank for your response but i'm getting error. Please check it

Compilation Error:
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ListViewExample.Models.EmployeeDetails' because 'ListViewExample.Models.EmployeeDetails' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Line 85:     <ul>
Line 86:         @foreach (ListViewExample.Models.EmployeeDetails ED in Model)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below to display your data in a list :

```
//if not already done set the model for your page
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails>
//........
<ul>
    @foreach (EmployeeDetails ED in Model)
    {

    <li>
      <section>@ED.FName</section>
      <section>@ED.LName</section>
      <section>@ED.Age</section>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```